# embedding youtube videos - aspect ratio

Tags: youtube, embed

I'm looking to embed some youtube videos in my web page and from looking at the videos on youtube they all seem to be displayed with an aspect ration of 16:9 or 640px:340px.

Trouble is I only have 600px max space to put them in, would I just work out the appropriate height i.e. 640/16*9 = 333px  and display them in that and would that take care of everything ,or is there any other size allocated for the progress bar at bottom.

E.g. if you look at this video you can see the progress bar throughout.

http://www.youtube.com/user/southerncomfort?v=ygeWsoYYMuQ

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose either 16:9 or 4:3, the later being 480px X 385px (+25px to height for controls).

OR, if you want 16:9, you can choose the size to be 560x315.

Check out the style guide: https://web.archive.org/web/20130415231312/http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178264

Answer (score 6):

You can use any youtube embed code generator to achieve your goal with ease.

1. Go to [Advanced Youtube Embed Code Generator.](https://codegena.com/generator/Youtube-Embed-Code-Generator/)
2. Enter the video ID and input either height or width in the
   respective column and hit generate button(the empty field will be
   automatically calculated with 16:9 ratio)
3. Copy the code and use it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still on this,

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp.

Ensure to use ALL CSS PROPERTIES AND STYLING enlisted else it won't render correctly on responsive sites and apps.